# How to implement a computed property like a abstract property in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I know there is no abstract class and either `Abstract` keyword in Swift. The following problem just like implementing a abstract property.

For convenient, supposed that there are three classes as following:

```
class SuperClass: NSManagedObject { // the compiler will complain without 'NSManagedObject', and I don't know why.
    public let superInt: Int = 1 // use superInt to represent other stored property for SuperClass.
}

class SubClass1: SuperClass {
    let subInt1: Int = 2 // use 'subInt1' to represent other stored property for SubClass1.
}
class SubClass2: SuperClass {
    let subInt2: Int = 3 // use 'subInt2' to represent other stored property for SubClass2.
}
protocol TestProtocol {
    var count: Int { get } // a computed property
    func printInt() // a custom method
}
```

Here, those classes are all objects defined in CoreData, especially SuperClass is a abstract Entity. I want to extend some interfaces(the `TestProtocol` above) for SuperClass, so that I can use polymorphism. I come up with 2 methods:

Method 1: let SuperClass confirms `TestProtocol`.

```
extension SuperClass: TestProtocol {
    var count: Int { return superInt }
    func printInt() { print("Here is SuperClass. Count: \(count)") }
}
extension SubClass1 {
    override var count: Int { return subInt1 }
    override func printInt() { print("Here is SubClass1. Count is \(count)") }
}
extension SubClass2 {
    override var count: Int { return subInt2 }
    override func printInt() { print("Here is SubClass2. Count is \(count)") }
}

// Here is the test code
let subClasses: [SuperClass] = [SubClass1(), SubClass2()]
subClasses.forEach { $0.printInt() }
```

Method 2: Convert subClasses to a protocol object.

```
extension SubClass1: TestProtocol {
    var count: Int { return subInt1 }
    func printInt() { print("Here is SubClass1. Count is \(count)") }
}
extension SubClass2: TestProtocol {
    var count: Int { return subInt2 }
    func printInt() { print("Here is SubClass1. Count is \(count)") }
}

// Here is the test code
let subClasses: [SuperClass] = [SubClass1(), SubClass2()]
subClasses.forEach { ($0 as! TestProtocol).printInt() }
```

In method 1, everything looks good. But I have to implement the code in SuperClass which is totally useless. The method seems like a little trick of grammar.

In method 2, all code is useful, but the conversion at last line broke the elegance of code. It makes me crazy continuously using code like `($0 as! TestProtocol).printInt()`.

I'm not satisfied with both methods. So which is recommended way or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your second method you actually do not need to use casting (`($0 as! TestProtocol).printInt()`). Here is how:

```
let subClasses: [TestProtocol] = [SubClass1(), SubClass2()]
subClasses.forEach { $0.printInt() }
```

By typing the `subClasses` array to `TestProtocol` instead of `SuperClass` you can remove the need for casting because the compiler now knows that every element in `subClasses` conforms to `TestProtocol` and thus, has a method `printInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your super class does not serve any purpose in both method 1 and method 2. In both methods you have defined, you want to eventually call printInt() which **should be common** to all sub classes. Notice I have highlighted "should be common". The purpose of a protocol is to specify requirements that conforming types must implement. Therefore, a protocol is sufficient to form the contract that your classes 1 and 2 should implement var count and func printInt(). Also a protocol is a type, so you do not need a super class to hold references to the other two classes as you did here:

```
    let subClasses: [SuperClass] = [SubClass1(), SubClass2()]
```

In my opinion, this would be a better way:

```
    protocol TestProtocol {
        var count: Int { get } // a computed property
        func printInt() // a custom method
    }

    Class1: TestProtocol {
        var subInt = 2
        var count: Int { return subInt1 }
        func printInt() { print("Here is SubClass1. Count is \(count)") }
    }

    Class2: TestProtocol {
        var subInt = 3
        var count: Int { return subInt2 }
        func printInt() { print("Here is SubClass2. Count is \(count)") }
    }

   let smallClasses: [TestProtocol] = [Class1(), Class2()]
   smallClasses.forEach { $0.printInt() }
```

This way of doing things fulfills the Protocol Oriented way of programming in Swift, which is the favored approach. Generally speaking, inheritance and subclassing is shunned in iOS design patterns and I will direct you to this blog post so you can learn more about why https://krakendev.io/blog/subclassing-can-suck-and-heres-why

**EDIT**

You have clarified your question a bit more so I am going to attempt to answer it better. You are looking for the equivalent of what is an abstract class in Java which are classes that contain one or more abstract methods. An abstract method in Java is a method that is declared, but contains no implementation. Abstract classes may not be instantiated, and require subclasses to provide implementations for the abstract methods.

Swift does not come with the same functionality but something that is functionaly equivalent would require a super class where all sub classes are forced to implement properties or methods that must be common to all sub classes. This is of course achieved by the protocol method I have shown above but you also require the ability to call properties or methods from the super class from the sub class which means each sub class must be able to cast as both the protocol type and the super class type.

Here is my solution to that written in Swift 3:

```
    protocol TestProtocol {
      var count: Int { get } // a computed property
      func printInt() // a custom method
    }

    //base class

    class SuperClass: TestProtocol {

      var sharedInt: Int = 0

      var subInt: Int = 1
      var count: Int { return subInt }
      func printInt() { print("Here is SubClass. Count is \(count)") }

    }

    class class1: SuperClass {

      override init(){
      super.init()
      self.subInt = 2
    }

    }

    class class2: SuperClass {

      override init(){
      super.init()
      self.subInt = 3
   }

   }

   //I can get count and printInt() which superClass, class1 and class2 share becuase of the protocol.

    let smallClasses: [TestProtocol] = [SuperClass(), class1(), class2()]

    smallClasses.forEach { $0.printInt() }

    //I can convert the sub classes to super class type and call their printInt method

    let smallClasses2: [SuperClass] = [class1(), class2()]

    smallClasses2.forEach { $0.printInt() }

    //I can get to the shared values the sub classes have from the super class

    smallClasses2.forEach { print($0.sharedInt) }
```

If you copy and paste the code above into a Playground in Xcode, you will receive the following output:

```
    Here is SubClass. Count is 1
    Here is SubClass. Count is 2
    Here is SubClass. Count is 3
    Here is SubClass. Count is 2
    Here is SubClass. Count is 3
    0
    0
```

Comment: Thanks for your blog link. Well, it's a good method. However, if I want to assess some properties defined in SuperClass, I had to convert the instances to SuperClass or SubClass. The perfect answer I want is to let the usage of SuperClass like a abstract class in Java.

Comment: I hear you bro. Of course there is no right or wrong way to implementing design patterns, so while I might disagree with the approach you want to use, only you understand the requirements of your project better. So I have edited my answer above and hopefully it has what you are looking for. Cheers.

Comment: Your new answer is similar to my method 1. Swift and Java is two different language. I may require swift for two much.